# How to get the output for the following code involving differentiation and integration?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics, machine-precision

I need to evaluate the following Mathematica code to get a numerical value as my output. But during compilation I get the error message

> NumericalMath`FixedPrecisionEvaluate::precbd: Requested precision ∞ is not a machine-sized real number between \$MinPrecision and $MaxPrecision.

Could anyone please help me to solve this issue.

This is my code:

```
ee = Integrate[
       (x - y)^(-(α - 1) - 1) ((y^(3))*(
          Sum[((Exp[I*1])*(1 - Exp[y *I*(λ)^s] ))/λ^(s*(2 - d)), {s, -20, 20}])), 
       {y, 0, x}];
ew = D[ee / Gamma[-(α - 1)], {x, 1}] /. x -> 1 /. λ -> 3 /. d -> 1.5 /. α -> 0.6
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
 ew /. x -> 1 /. λ -> 3 /. d -> 1.5 /. α -> .6;
```

Try

```
 ew = ew /. x -> 1 /. λ -> 3 /. d -> 15/10 /. α -> 6/10;
```

And only now do

```
 N[ew]

 (* 1.25149 + 5.85725 I *)
```

This avoids the `` NumericalMath`FixedPrecisionEvaluate::precbd `` issue in V 12.1.

Comment: What *is* ``NumericalMath`FixedPrecisionEvaluate`` ?